# Do actions added with extraReducers on createSlice have the slice's name prefix added to their types?

Tags: redux, reducers, redux-toolkit

From the official doc's example:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation

```
import { createAction, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const incrementBy = createAction<number>('incrementBy')
const decrement = createAction('decrement')

createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(incrementBy, (state, action) => { // DO SOMETHING })
      .addCase(decrement,   (state, action) => { // DO SOMETHING })
      .addDefaultCase((state, action) => {})
  },
})
```

Also from the docs:

[image]

> One of the key concepts of Redux is that each slice reducer "owns" its slice of state, and that many slice reducers can independently respond to the same action type. extraReducers allows createSlice to respond to other action types besides the types it has generated.

**QUESTION**

In the example above, will the cases `incrementBy` and `decrement` also get the `counter` name as a prefix in their types?

Like:

```
"counter/incrementBy"
"counter/decrement"
```

Is this how the `extraReducers` property work?

Comment: The point of `extraReducers` is to react to actions that are dispatched from another source. As "another source" implies that no action creators are generated from them and so the slice has "no control", nothing could possibly be added to the action type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the entire point of `extraReducers` is that it does *not* generate any new action types.

`extraReducers` exists so that **a slice reducer can listen to *other* action types that have already been defined outside the slice**.

Answer (score 1):

No. It does not get the name prefix.

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-dew-35ivq

[image]

```
import { createAction, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface CounterState {
  value: number;
}

export const decrementV2 = createAction('decrement');

const initialState = { value: 0 } as CounterState;

const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment(state,action) {
      console.log(`action.type: ${action.type}`);
      state.value++;
    },
    decrement(state,action) {
      console.log(`action.type: ${action.type}`);
      state.value--;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(decrementV2, (state, action) => {
      console.log("FROM decrementV2 (from extraReducers)")
      console.log(`action.type: ${action.type}`);
      state.value--;
    });
  }
});

export const { increment, decrement } = counterSlice.actions;
export default counterSlice.reducer;
```